# mapquest geocoding data mismatch

Tags: geocoding, mapquest, nominatim

I am new to mapquest,

What is the difference b/w open.mapquest.* and mapquest.* ?.  As I seen somewhere open.mapquest gives data only from open source data(OSM) with nominatim api.

In some cases i got diff result from http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search and open.mapquest. Why it differs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The open version of the MapQuest apis only uses OSM data while the www version uses licensed data in addition to the OSM data.

MapQuest is currently on an older version of Nominatim and can/will return different results.